# How to give RAM to the filesystem cache

Tags: linux, memory, elasticsearch

I am tuning my linux machine running Elasticsearch. It says that I should give at least half the memory of the machine running elasticsearch to the filesystem cache. But I don't know how much of it is given currently to filesystem cache. How to find it? And how to change it to half of the RAM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't *give* memory to the file system cache, because it is part of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

You may need to have enough physical RAM to make that possible (so you might need to buy more RAM).

See also [LinuxAteMyRam](http://linuxatemyram.com/) (which explains that "free" RAM is used in the page cache for file data), and use the [free(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) command (also [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) & [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), or even [htop(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html)...). See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Of course, if you have big processes running (outside of Elasticsearch) you might terminate or stop them.

See also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).

Comment: +1.  While it's obvious to someone who already knows how linux filesystem caching works, if someone is asking about it, IMO it would be a good idea to explicitly state that Linux automatically uses free ram to cache files, and automatically releases memory from the cache when a program needs it (even if that's stated several times in the URLs you linked to).  i.e. it just works and there's no manual tuning needed.